# How to prevent harddisk from spinning up and down?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, hdparm

I recently added a Toshiba Enterprise MG06ACA10TE 10TB disk to one of my servers.

Since then, I receive between 5-15 of these messages in syslog every day:

```
smartd[625]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], CHECK POWER STATUS spins up disk (0x80 -> 0xff)
```

As I understand it, this means that the hard drive is spinning down when it has been at idle for a while in order to save power.

I fear this causes unnecessary wear on my spinning HDD.

Should I ignore these log messages - or should I somehow tell the disk to not spin down?

I tend to think the latter is the right choice. But how do I tell the disk to not spin down?

I have been looking at 'hdparm' options but not sure what option will instruct the drive to not spin down.
I have tried hdparm -B /dev/sdb, it says:

```
# hdparm -B /dev/sdb 

/dev/sdb:
 APM_level      = 254
```

man page for hdparm says the following about the -B option:

```
Get/set  Advanced  Power  Management  feature, if the drive supports it. A low value means 
aggressive power management and a high value means better performance.  Possible settings range 
from values 1 through 127 (which
permit spin-down), and values 128 through 254 (which do not permit spin-down).  The highest 
degree of power management is attained with a setting of 1, and the highest I/O performance with 
a setting of 254.  A value  of 255 tells hdparm to disable Advanced Power Management altogether 
on the drive (not all drives support disabling it, but most do).
```

So should I try the 255 value? Or are there other problems involved with disabling APM altogether?